# What formula can I use to change 5/19/2014 to 5/2014 date in Excel?

Tags: excel

What formula to use to change 5/19/2014 to 5/2014 date in Excel?  I need to change the actual cell, not just the format.  In other words, I need to convert the month, day, year into a month and year only.

Comment: What is the format of the cell, Date / String ?

Comment: Its a date format, eg, type in 5/19/2014 and its formatted as a custom format m/d/yyyy

Comment: If you want The cell to still contain a date, it's going to need to have a day...

Answer (score 0):

Use `TEXT` like this:

```
=TEXT(A1, "m/yyyy")
```

Is this what you're trying?